# iOS: cannot request authorization from Spotify app

Tags: iphone, swift3, ios10, spotify

I'm developping app using spotify-iOS-SDK, i have succesfully connect my app to Spotify from Safari, but when i try to connect my app from Spotify App, it doesn't request authorization in spotify app, instead it throw me back to my app after a checkmark icon show in Spotify and it caused crash to my app because the session is null.

This is my code:

```
var auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()!
auth.redirectURL     = URL(string: ENV.SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URL
auth.clientID        = ENV.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID
auth.requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope, SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope, 
    SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPublicScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPrivateScope]

    if SPTAuth.supportsApplicationAuthentication(){
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(auth.spotifyAppAuthenticationURL())
    }else{
        if UIApplication.shared.openURL(auth.spotifyWebAuthenticationURL()){
            if auth.canHandle(auth.redirectURL) {
                // To do - build in error handling

            }
        }

    }
```

I have put spotify-action in my LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. What am i doing wrong here? I saw DemoProject from https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk
and it worked. It should request authorization right after my app go to Spotify App

Comment: What code do you have in your `AppDelegate` under `openURL`?

Answer (score 0):

You need some code in your `AppDelegate` that looks like follows:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        let auth = SPTAuth()
        if auth.canHandle(auth.redirectURL) {
            auth.handleAuthCallback(withTriggeredAuthURL: url, callback: { (error, session) in
            // Do other things to save session...
            return true
        }

        return false


}
```

Comment: that's not the problem, i have put that handler in my AppDelegate, the actual problem is my bundleID in my app and SpotifyDashboard is different :)

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved my issues, the problem is my Bundle ID in my app is different from my BundleID in my Spotify Dashboard.
https://developer.spotify.com/my-applications

Just match my bundle ID and it worked!